# set function does not trigger an update in React with Recoil

Tags: reactjs, setstate, recoiljs

This seems like it should be easy but why isn't a button callback function with a setState call not triggering a refresh of the data item? Actually it's just the computeSMA button that isn't changing the sma when the button is selected. The other two callbacks to set inputs work. The fetchData updates the charts so i can't figure this out!! Must be too tired ...

````
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { useRecoilState } from "recoil";
import { closingDataAtom, metaDataAtom, tickerAtom, timeSeriesAtom , smaAtom} from '../../utils/atoms'
import { Container } from '@material-ui/core'
import '../../utils/Home.css'
import { VictoryChart, VictoryBar, VictoryTheme, VictoryVoronoiContainer, VictoryLine, VictoryBrushContainer, VictoryZoomContainer } from 'victory';
import { Chart, Axis, Tooltip, Line, Point } from "bizcharts";
import {XYPlot, LineSeries} from 'react-vis';






const APIKEY = 'demo'


const Home = () => {

  const [apikey, setApiKey] = useState(APIKEY)
  const [ticker, setTicker] = useRecoilState(tickerAtom);
  const [metadata, setMetaData] = useRecoilState(metaDataAtom)
  const [closingdata, setClosingData] = useRecoilState(closingDataAtom)
  const [dates, setDates] = useRecoilState(timeSeriesAtom)
  const [sma, setSMA] = useRecoilState(smaAtom)
  const TIME_RESOLUTION = 'Daily'
  var requestUrl

  if (TIME_RESOLUTION === 'Daily') {
    requestUrl = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=" + ticker + "&outputsize=full&apikey=" + apikey
  } else {
    requestUrl = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY_ADJUSTED&symbol=" + ticker + "&outputsize=full&apikey=" + apikey;
  }

  const fetchData = async () => {
    fetch(requestUrl)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        var closing_price = []
        var metadata = []
        var dat = []
        Object.keys(data['Time Series (Daily)']).forEach((dateKey) => {
          closing_price.push(data['Time Series (Daily)'][dateKey]['5. adjusted close'])
          dat.push({ 'date': new Date(dateKey) })
        })
        Object.keys(data['Meta Data']).forEach((metaKey) => {
          metadata.push(data['Meta Data'][metaKey])
        })
        setDates(dat.reverse())
        setClosingData(closing_price.reverse())
        setMetaData(metadata)

      })
      .catch(e => {
     
      });
  };

  const handleSMACompute = (e) => {
      var sm = ['2', '3', '4']
      setSMA(sm)  <====== REACT IS NOT "REACTING"    
}

  
  const handleTickerInput = (e) => {
    setTicker(e.target.value)

  }

  const handleAPIInput = (e) => {
    setApiKey(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Container className="container" maxWidth="sm">

        <div>
          <label>Ticker:</label> {ticker}
          <input type="text" name="ticker" onChange={handleTickerInput} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>APIKEY:</label> {apikey}
          <input type="text" name="apikey" onChange={handleAPIInput} />
        </div>

        <button onClick={fetchData}>
          Click it
            </button>
        <Container className="container" maxWidth="sm">
          <ul>{metadata}</ul>
        </Container>

        
          <button OnClick={handleSMACompute}> Generate  SMA    </button>
          <Container className="container" maxWidth="sm">
          <ul>The value is {sma}</ul>
        </Container><div>
       

        </div>

        <VictoryChart
          theme={VictoryTheme.material}
          domainPadding={10}
        >
          <VictoryBar
            style={{ data: { fill: "#c43a31" } }}
            data={closingdata}
          />
        </VictoryChart>
        <div>
          <VictoryChart
            theme={VictoryTheme.material}
          >
            <VictoryLine
              style={{
                data: { stroke: "#c43a31" },
                parent: { border: "1px solid #ccc" }
              }}
              animate={{
                duration: 20,
                onLoad: { duration: 20 }
              }}
              containerComponent={<VictoryZoomContainer zoomDomain={{x: [5, 35], y: [0, 100]}}/>}
              categories={{
                y: dates
              }}
            
              
              
              data={closingdata}
            />
          </VictoryChart>
        </div>
 
      </Container>
    </>
  );


}```
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been the button setup. I changed to this and it works....??ggrrrr

```
          Click it
            </button>
        <Container className="container" maxWidth="sm">
          <li>{metadata}</li>
        </Container>

        <button onClick={computeSMA}>
          Click it
            </button>
        <Container className="container" maxWidth="sm">
          <li>{sma}</li>
        </Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, you used OnClick as the event name. Should be onClick. It is a react syntax and it is case sensitive.